# Polymer 2.0 - custom component not showing

Tags: html, polymer, custom-component

I just start learning `polymer` 2.0 and I do a quick test:

```
long-calendar-app.html:
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">
<dom-module id="long-calendar-app">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <h2>Hello [[prop1]]</h2>
    <my-view1 name="view1"></my-view1><!--Added to test and see if it works-->
  </template>

  <script>
    class MyApplication extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'long-calendar-app'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          prop1: {
            type: String,
            value: 'long-calendar-app'
          }
        };
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(MyApplication.is, MyApplication);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

and just copy `MyView1` from `starter-kit`:

```
my-view1.html:
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">

<dom-module id="my-view1">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
        display: block;

        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="circle">1</div>
      <h1>View One</h1>
      <p>Ut labores minimum atomorum pro. Laudem tibique ut has.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, per in nusquam nominavi periculis, sit elit oportere ea.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, per in nusquam nominavi periculis, sit elit oportere ea.Cu mei vide viris gloriatur, at populo eripuit sit.</p>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    class MyView1 extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'my-view1'; }
    }

    window.customElements.define(MyView1.is, MyView1);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

As you can see I already add `<my-view1 name="view1"></my-view1>` below `<h2>Hello [[prop1]]</h2>`. But it did not render in browser.

How can I resolve this?

**Update01:**

I just check my developer console and it seems like I do not have `#shadow-root` in `my-view1`:
[image]

In the starter-kit it should be:
[image]

Do this mean that the rendering is not happening for `my-view1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import my-view1 into the long-calendar-app.html.

i.e. `<link rel="import" href="../my-view1/my-view-1.html">`

Comment: It works. However, why didn't I see any of the import in the `starter-kit`? What do they do differently?

Comment: In the PSK they use fragments to lazy load the views as detailed in the polymer.json file:
`"fragments": [
    "src/my-view1.html",
    "src/my-view2.html",
    "src/my-view3.html",
    "src/my-view404.html"
],`